# Can I use a numeric popup?

Tags: android, popup, numeric

I'm trying to get a numeric pop-up . It should be like the calendar but only a range of numbers. Can anyone give me an idea, a link or any suggestion?

Comment: Check out library (not mine) https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NumberPicker` if your min API level is 11 or greater.